# I need to save the image coordinates in a txt file by clicking on mouse

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

what's up guys. I'm very beginner on programing stuffs. So, I need to create a code that I click on the image and it salve its coordinate. I need to make it in python+opencv. I've already done something, however it does not save its coordinate.
First of all, open an image.
Second, click on the pixel.
Third, save the pixel information (column, line) in txt file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

def callback(event):
    print ('event.x, event.y')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', callback)
def callback(event):
    print ('event.xdata, event.ydata')




img = cv2.imread('/home/dgt/Pictures/1.jpeg',-1)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')



plt.show()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You are redefining `callback` so of course the first 'version' is lost...

Comment: So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

With this script you can click on an image, and save the click locations to a spreadsheet:

```
import cv2, numpy as np

# Path to source video:
output_path = '/home/stephen/Desktop/clicks.csv'

# Mouse callback function
global click_list
positions, click_list = [], []
def callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == 1: click_list.append((x,y))
cv2.namedWindow('img')
cv2.setMouseCallback('img', callback)

img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/test214.png')

# Mainloop - show the image and collect the data
while True:
    cv2.imshow('img', img)    
    # Wait, and allow the user to quit with the 'esc' key
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    # If user presses 'esc' break 
    if k == 27: break        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Write data to a spreadsheet
import csv
with open(output_path, 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['x_position', 'y_position']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for position in click_list:
        x, y = position[0], position[1]
        writer.writerow({'x_position': x, 'y_position': y})
```